# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier while Parsin XML Data Using Google App Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I am getting leave data from Leave system via API and posting this to a google sheet and below is the sample response xml response.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>
<DataService>
    <Request ID="1253" Status="Approved">
        <TimeOffDate>2020-02-07</TimeOffDate>
        <TimeOffDayOfWeek>Friday</TimeOffDayOfWeek>
        <TimeStart></TimeStart>
        <TimeEnd></TimeEnd>
        <TimeOffHours>8.000</TimeOffHours>
        <TimeOffTypeName>Annual Vacation</TimeOffTypeName>
        <LoginID>testuser</LoginID>
        <Firstname>test</Firstname>
        <Lastname>user</Lastname>
        <UserCategory></UserCategory>
        <SubmittedDate>2019-10-03</SubmittedDate>
        <Deducted>Yes</Deducted>
        <Comment>
            <![CDATA[* time-off request created by administrator]]>
        </Comment>
    </Request>
```

Below is the code that I use to get the data and set it to Google sheet. My challenge is, I am not sure on how to get the attribute **ID** and **Status** from the response and push it to the requestObjects array. each time I try to push the attribute using **request.getAttribute("ID")**, I get an error
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

```
       };
  var url = 'https://data.purelyhr.com/xml?ak=' + ak + '&sDate=' + start + '&eDate=' + end + '&TimeOffTypeName'+ '&page=' + pages;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
  var document = XmlService.parse(response);
  var root = document.getRootElement();

  //set variables to data from PurelyHR
  var requestElements = root.getChildren('Request'); // Get all <Request> elements
  var requestObjects = []; // Request objects for logging / eventual printing
  for (var i = 0; i < requestElements.length; i++) {
  var request = requestElements[i]; // A single <Request> element
  var Status = request.getAttribute("Status").getValue();

    // Add to requestObjects array
    requestObjects.push({
      Status:request.getAttribute("Status"),
      TimeOffDate: request.getChild('TimeOffDate').getText(),
      TimeOffDayOfWeek: request.getChild('TimeOffDayOfWeek').getText(),
      TimeStart: request.getChild('TimeStart').getText(),
      TimeEnd: request.getChild('TimeEnd').getText(),
      TimeOffHours: request.getChild('TimeOffHours').getText(),
      TimeOffTypeName: request.getChild('TimeOffTypeName').getText(),
      LoginID: request.getChild('LoginID').getText(),
      Firstname: request.getChild('Firstname').getText(),
      Lastname: request.getChild('Lastname').getText(),
      UserCategory: request.getChild('UserCategory').getText(),
      SubmittedDate: request.getChild('SubmittedDate').getText(),
      Deducted: request.getChild('Deducted').getText(),
      Comment: request.getChild('Comment').getText()
    });
  }
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
 var range = sheet.getRange("A2:J").getValue();
 for (var j = 0; j < requestObjects.length; j++) {
        sheet.getRange(2 + j, 1).setValue(requestObjects[j].Status)
        sheet.getRange(2 + j, 2).setValue(requestObjects[j].Firstname)
        sheet.getRange(2 + j, 3).setValue(requestObjects[j].Lastname)
        sheet.getRange(2 + j, 4).setValue(requestObjects[j].LoginID);
        sheet.getRange(2 + j, 5).setValue(requestObjects[j].TimeOffTypeName);
        sheet.getRange(2 + j, 6).setValue(requestObjects[j].TimeOffDayOfWeek);
        sheet.getRange(2 + j, 7).setValue(requestObjects[j].SubmittedDate);
        sheet.getRange(2 + j, 8).setValue(requestObjects[j].TimeOffHours)
        sheet.getRange(2 + j, 9).setValue(requestObjects[j].TimeOffDate)
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(requestObjects));
}

}
```

Results on G sheet

[image]

Comment: The ID and Status fields of the object don't have property names.

Comment: @Just I can't replicate this. It's probably, as Pointy wrote, that one of the <Request> elements doesn't have an ID or Status attribute.

Comment: Can I ask you about your result you expect?

Comment: @Tanaike, My intention is to get Status as a string, that is **Approved** or **Cancelled**, but what am getting is **[Status='Approved']** and is not what I want

Comment: @Tanaike, Thanks a lot. I modified and it works. And by the way, you understood me correctly.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that TheAddonDepot's answer can resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you invoke the `getAttribute()` function on an `Element` instance, it returns an instance of the `Attribute` class. You then need to call `getValue()` on that `Attribute` instance. For example:

```js
var id = request.getAttribute("ID").getValue();
```

Note that the value returned is always of type `String`.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. I have done this as indicated in my edited code, what I get in the G sheet seems to be odd. Please look at the editted question. Thanks

Comment: @Just Don't just copy-n-paste example code; try to understand the logic behind it and then apply it to your use case. Look at your code to see where you should be calling the `getValue()` method (hint...where else are you calling the `getAttribute()` function).